# How to handle Sparql endpoint disconnection in Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I'm to trying to execute a set of SPARQL queries on http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql  from my Java code, using Jena 2.11.

Here is my sample code:

```
Try{ 
    String SPARQLquery="SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?P) AS ?COUNT) "
                      +"WHERE{"
                      +"       values ?S {<"+MyResource1+">}." 
                      +"       values ?O {<"+MyResource2+">}."
                      +"       ?S ?P ?O."   
                      + "}";

    QueryExecution qe =QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql", SPARQLquery);        
    com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results = queryExec.execSelect();

} catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();   
   System.exit(1);
}
```

The problem is that, when the OpenLink server is shutdown for moments, it return wrong result (wrong ?COUNT in my example) instead of returning error code.

It's important in my task to detect if the returned result is correct or wrong, since I have to execute thousands of queries without the time to check the result of each one.

It would be perfect for me to stop the loop when detecting the first wrong result.

Thank you

Comment: how to you want to detect a "wrong count"? if the service is down, a 503 error will be returned, but not a wrong count value.

Comment: by the way, Virtuoso has the anytime behaviour, thus, you might get a count value for just what could be found before a timeout. that's called a partial result and stated in the HTTP response header, but clearly not in the Jena API.

Comment: Moreover, Jena 2.11 is from 2015 ...

Comment: The `count` aggregate function is going to be evaluated server-side. As @AKSW said, if you are getting any answer, it's because the server answered. If you are getting varying answers, it's not due to connectivity.

Comment: So, how to know if the returned result was complete or partial solution ?
In both case, server seems to return code 200. Is there a manner to know the real status of the query ?

Comment: I read here: https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/dbpedia-usage-report-as-of-2018-01-01-8cae1b81ca71
That the Virtuoso includes "X-SQL-Message" in response header to indicate that it's incomplete results. However, I can't get access to the response headers. Any help please ?

Comment: Yes @RobHall. I understand now the principle of the "Anytime Query". Now I want to read headers of the response to check if it contains "X-SQL-Message: RC...: Returning incomplete results, query interrupted by result timeout".

Comment: In that case, you have to use the "lower level" API of Jena, i.e. create a new `HttpQuery httpQuery = ...`, execute it with `InputStream in = httpQuery.exec()`, check the response header via `httpQuery.getResponseMessage` and then parse the stream with `ResultSetMgr.read(in, lang);`

Comment: I finally opted to handle my problem by adding a queryExec.setTimeout(30000), in this manner, when timeout is thrown, the program stop instead of inserting wrong incomplete result.
What do you think about this solution @AKSW.
Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Once the query has a cached and complete result, it will return in near-zero time. Until then, your `queryExec.setTimeout(30000)` may be viable *IFF* you have also included a *higher* timeout value in the query itself (such that your local timeout is hit first) *AND* that higher query timeout is lower than the server's configured time limit (so the Anytime Query feature doesn't kick in).